How to use lua-ul to make double underline (same as uuline in ulem)
Problem
As the title shows.
Due to some compatibility reasons, I am unable to use the ulem macro package in my tex project (complied by luatex). Therefore, I've replaced it with lua-ul package (https://tug.ctan.org/macros/luatex/latex/lua-ul/lua-ul.pdf).
However, now I find that the macro package does not provide a double underline scheme or example, and as a beginner, I do not know how to customize it...
What should I do to make the following example have the same scheme  of double underline as ulem package shows?
I've tried to ask gpt but it give me wrong answer.
What I want:

% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,UTF8]{ctexrep}
\usepackage{ulem}% just for test
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\newcommand{\uul}[1]{%
    #1%HERE IS WHAT I NEED (just use lua-ul)
}

\begin{document}
\noindent TEST『\uuline{This is a sentence for testing ulem double underline.}』TEST\\
\noindent 测试测试『\uul{This is a sentence for testing lua-ul double underline.}』测试测试
\end{document}


Wrong answer (gpt)
\newunderlinetype\beginDoubleUnderline{%  
    \leaders\hbox{%  
        \leaders\hbox{%  
        \vrule height .5ex depth .5ex\kern 0.2ex % first uline
        \vrule height .5ex depth .5ex            % second uline 
    }\hfill  
    }%  
}
\NewDocumentCommand\uul{+m}{{%
    \beginDoubleUnderline#1%
}}


A double underline is just a nesting of two underlines:
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,UTF8]{ctexrep}
\usepackage{ulem}% just for test
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\newcommand{\uul}[1]{%
  \underLine[bottom=\dimexpr-.58ex+1pt\relax, height=.08ex]{%
    \underLine[top=-.58ex, height=.08ex]{%
      #1%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\showoutput
\setbox0\hbox{j}
\showthe\dp0
\showthe\dimexpr 1ex\relax
\noindent TEST『\uuline{This is a sentence for testing ulem double underline.}』TEST\\
\noindent 测试测试『\uul{This is a sentence for testing lua-ul double underline.}』测试测试
\end{document}



Thank you for your answer. I was overthinking it...
